# Unknown action error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, action

I have created a custom action `req` inside my membership controller and defined routes for it.But when i give path to that custom action on link_to ,it gives me error saying that unknown action ,The action 'show' could not be found for MembershipsController.I dny understand why it goes to find show action when i am giving path to my custom action.

Following is my custom action inside membership controller

```
def req
  @user =User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  @group =params[:group_id]
  unless @group.nil?
    if Membership.request(@user.id, @group)
       redirect_to :back, :notice => 'Joined successfully.'
    else
      redirect_to :back,  :notice => 'couldnot Joine.'
    end
  end
end
```

There is no show action inside my memberships controller.

Following is the route for my custom action :

```
resources :memberships do
  collection do
    post 'req'
  end
end
```

Following is the code inside my `groups/show.html.haml` where i am giving path of custom action..

```
  - if @collegemates.empty?
    %p.info You have no common collegemates ...
  - else
    %table.datatable
      %thead
        %tr
          ...
      %tbody
        - @collegemates.each do |c|
          - unless Membership.group_member(c.id, @group)
            %tr
              %td= c.full_name
              %td= c.email
              %td= link_to "request to join",{:controller => :memberships, :action => "req",:email =>c.email,:group_id => @group.id},:method => "post"
```

When i click on request to join I am getting that unknown action error for show action. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you included Rails' javascripts? Rails uses javascript, so that your link does a post request. If you didn't include the javascript you perform a get request instead of a post request.

Comment: how to include this  javascript...create is also a post request isnt it?my create action is working fine which means my post request is working fyn..

Comment: Create probably does work, because it's a normal form with a button. This is a link, so you need javascript to make it do a post. You have to include the javascript in the `head` tag of you layout file like this: `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? And can you show the generated html for your `link_to`?

Comment: am using rails 3.0.3.Following is the generated html for the link    <a href="/memberships/req?email=nikitasalunkhe_3%40yahoo.com&amp;group_id=12" data-method="post" rel="nofollow">request to join</a>

Comment: If that is the generated html, it's a problem with your javascript. Rails 3.0.3 doesn't use the asset pipeline yet, so instead of `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` you should do `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`

Comment: i have purposely removed defaults...coz m makimg use of ajax in some files so to make my ajax work i removed defaults..

Comment: No sure why you need to remove defaults to make your Ajax work but, you at least need rails.js. Try `<%= javascript_include_tag 'rails' %>`.

Comment: thanks Mischa ur solution solved my issue but can u tell me 1 thing is it necessary to remove any reference to javascript include :defaults to make ajax work...if i dnt remove :defaults will my ajax still work

Comment: Your Ajax should still work with defaults. Where did you get the idea that you have to remove every reference to defaults??

Comment: I added the solution as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: i was referring one tutorial in that it was mentioned to remove remove any reference to javascript include :defaults.I am very thankful for ur guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a link do a POST request, you need javascript. Rails takes care of this for you, but you do have to include the necessary files. Adding `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` to your layouts file will solve your problem. If you don't do this a GET request will be performed instead of a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to assign your action either to collection or to member.

```
resources :memberships do
  post 'req', :on => :collection # or :member
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions.

`:on => :collection` creates a route like `memberships/req` where
`:on => :member` gives you a route for an object like `memberships/:id/req`.

Comment: But he already has `collection do`, which is the same as `:on => :collection`. This is just different syntax for what he already has.

Comment: ah, didn't see that because of the wrong code formatting, you're right

Answer (score 0):

As default rails gives the CRUD actions.

```
new,create,edit,update,delete
```

the code

```
collection do
  post 'req'
end
```

will create the route as below.

```
/memberships/req
```

So rails misunderstands that you are requesting /memberships/:id
and tries to match the show action.as the there is no show action it raises unknown action.

So the solution is you need to inform that you are not using CRUD actions

It can be done as below

```
resources :memberships, :only => [] do
 collection do
   post 'req'
 end
end
```

Comment: You are right about the problem, but your solution is wrong. Rails thinks he needs the show action because he is performing a GET request. If it were a POST request everything would be fine.

Comment: sounder i tried ur solution but i am getting new error saying No route matches "/memberships/req"..

Comment: Mischa it is a post request...when i do rake routes it shows req_memberships POST   /memberships/req(.:format)                     {:controller=>"memberships", :action=>"req"} that means it is a post request..

Comment: @NJF, as I am trying to explain above: it's NOT a post request, because you don't have to necessary javascript that takes care of that.

Comment: @NJF Please paste the exact log message while getting this error.

Comment: @soundar, it's just a get request instead of a post. See my answer for the solution.